iOS returns an error regarding React-Codegen from project Pods Explicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in stopped
When I run the command  npx react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone 15 Pro" in my terminal on my Mac M1 receive this error
PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/databasket/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DbAttendance-azvmhjqlipxdpkgernpvlryirpgy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Script-46EB2E00026CE0.sh (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')

I'm running react native 0.74.3, ruby version 2.6.10, cocoapods version 1.15.2, node version 21.7.3, Xcode version 15.4  Here's  my installed packages in relation to react-native as-well as some system information
System:
    OS: macOS 14.4.1
    Xcode:15.4
    ios:17.5
    
 npmPackages:
    react: 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.74.3

I had deleted DerivedData of Xcode and Podfile.lock,Pods and node_modules.And I run command yarn install and pod install and npc react-native run-ins but not work


Open your iOS (folder) project file using Xcode.
Run your project.
You will encounter the error. Click on the error and when you hover on the error line it'll show fix button. Press it and save it.
Run again from Xcode.
If it runs successfully, then you can run it from vscode terminal as well.

PS: If error exists, please mention the error shown in the Xcode.
